C Embedded - What is the correct way for allocating memory and building around that memory inside STM32?
I am building a system with STM32 that uses a device that needs to be calibrated (the data can be stored in one 32 bit register). Since I am still building and updating the code, I ideally would like the region to stay in the same place so every time I build and power on it doesn't have to recalibrate. Obviously its a given that the MCU doesn't initialize the values in that region given it's calibration data.
Right now I've just picked a far flung address inside the flash region, and am hoping the compiler doesn't write over it. It works perfectly, but it feels like there is a proper way to block out memory from the compiler side.

Normally you'd configure this through a custom segment in your linker script, then either download default values along with the program or otherwise set it to "no init" and maintain previous values - to be written by a bootloader or similar in run-time. This should ideally be eeprom or data flash, so that you don't have to erase a large chunk of it each time you update the value. And so that you don't have to use evil tricks like executing the flashing algorithm out of RAM because code in flash can't execute while the program flash is being re-programming.

It is not clear what you you are asking.  Presumably this calibration data should be non-volatile?  For that you might use the "backup registers" if your particular STM32 has them, but for that you will also require battery back-up - they are only non-volatile in the sense that they they have an independent power supply .  Failing that an external EEPROM.  Saving such data to the on-chip flash is possible but inefficient - you would necessarily dedicate an entire flash page to it.  No-init sections only apply to SRAM, and that is not non-volatile - the data will be lost when you loose power.

Note also that your question has little specific to embedded C or memory management or even stm32cubeide - do not spam the tags.  It has everything to do with your specific hardware with respect to NV storage capability and power supply arrangements.  You have not been specific on that.

The "compiler" does not write over anything - the behaviour you are referring to is a matter for the linker.  Using flash memory for this is problematic and while it is word-writable, it is page-erasable.  Most STM32 parts have large and variable length page sizes.  Smaller parts may have equal sized pages but even then they are likely to be 2Kb or more in size.

Some STM32 parts I think have EEPROM emulation.  Again you need to be specific.  Writing "variable" data to Flash is less than ideal.

@Clifford apologies - this feels like one of those questions right in between EE and Stack overflow. I indeed am looking for a way to configure a non volatile memory region on my STM32 flash, using my IDE (cube IDE). I think the specific address regions are HW specific, but how one goes about writing that into the programming in a proper way I am not sure, aside from just picking an unused address and hoping for the best like I currently am.

MCU-agnostic advice: Putting the calibration data in one of the last pages of the Flash memory can be feasible if you can somehow ensure that your software upgrade images are never large enough to overwrite those pages.  You should also have a redundant copy (or two) on
separate flash pages, whose integrity is ensured by checksums or ECCs.  If a bitflip ever occurred on any one of those calibration datum, you would either want to correct it, or mark it as bad (never to be trusted) and use one of the redundant copies.

Well if you must do it that way, clearly picking some arbitrary address is not acceptable.  The answer is to reserve the space via the linker script, either by omission or explicitly creating a named region.  However what I am saying is that is unlikely to be an acceptable solution.  All the likely methods typically involve non,,-volatile storage that is not memory mapped or not in normal memory visible to the linker.

@AndyJ given that the flash pages at the end of flash on an STM32 are on larger parts as large as 128K, that might not be practical advice.  Since the flash you are proposing is also the code memory, any possibility of a "bitflip" has far wider consequences than just this data -it is not a practical consideration.  A more likely scenario is power failure during an erase or write operation.

Either way, if you want best advice, you need to be specific about the MCU, and board you are using. As it is this is an X-Y problem.  You are asking how to do something that is probably not the best solution to the real problem, which is how to store calibration data.  It would also be helpful to understand when the calibration is performed.

Very straight forward process. Firstly, a memory region is established in the linker (.ld) file:
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 24K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 128K
  CALIBRATION (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0801FFE0,   LENGTH = 8 /* new 8 byte section */
}

Then in the sections part a few lines down, I added:
.calibration (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.calibration))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >CALIBRATION

The key part is the NOLOAD, which ensures that the values inside are not initialised on startup.
Then in the main file, you just need to add the pointer and address for reading and writing:
volatile uint32_t *calibration_value = (uint32_t *)0x0801FFE0; // create pointer at address
InitialCalib = *calibration_value; // use deferenced pointer to access data


You should avoid the magic number in the code. Define the symbol in the linker script using PRODIVE: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE.html see also: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/REGION_005fALIAS.html
